# event.save() gives error in Django

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x, sqlite

I am getting sqlite3 Integrity Error - Datatype Mismatch. But 
`python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py makemigrations` 
run well. My form data is valid. I am getting this error if I try to save the data to the database by making use of `event.save` in views.

My model is:

```
class createEvent(models.Model):
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    EventName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    EventOrganizer = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Date = models.DateField()
    LastDateOfRegistration = models.DateField()
    EventDetails = models.TextField()
```

My views.py is

```
def create_event(request):
    title = "Drizzlelore"
    subtitle = "Create event"
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = createEventForm.createEventForm(request.POST)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            fname = form.cleaned_data.get('FirstName')
            lname = form.cleaned_data.get('LastName')
            eventName = form.cleaned_data.get('EventName')
            eventOrganizer = form.cleaned_data.get('EventOrganizer')
            location = form.cleaned_data.get('Location')
            date = form.cleaned_data.get('Date')
            lastDateofReg = form.cleaned_data.get('LastDateOfRegistration')
            eventDetails = form.cleaned_data.get('EventDetails')
            event = form.save(commit=False)
            event.save()
            context = {
                "title":title,
                "subtitle":subtitle,
                "form" : form,
            }
            return HttpResponse("Success form submitted")
        else:
            print("Form not valid")
            return HttpResponse("Failure")
    else:
        form = createEventForm.createEventForm() 
        context = {
            "title":title,
            "subtitle":subtitle,
            "form":form,
        }
    return render(request,"home/createevents.html",context)
```

My form is

```
class createEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = createEvent
        fields = [
            'FirstName',
            'LastName',
            'EventName',
            'EventOrganizer',
            'Location',
            'Date',
            'LastDateOfRegistration',
            'EventDetails',
        ]
```

**EDIT:**

This is the fields which are getting displayed in the model when executed on the interactive shell.

```
>>> createEvent._meta.get_fields()
(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, <django.db.models.fields.CharField: FirstName>, <django.db.models.fields.CharField: LastName>, <django.db.models.field
s.CharField: EventName>, <django.db.models.fields.CharField: EventOrganizer>, <django.db.models.fields.CharField: Location>, <django.db.models.fields.DateField:
 Date>, <django.db.models.fields.DateField: LastDateOfRegistration>, <django.db.models.fields.TextField: EventDetails>)
```

This is the full error trace:

```
Internal Server Error: /drizzlelore/createEvents
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backe
nds\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backe
nds\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\mysite\home\views.py", line 67, in creat
e_event
    event.save()
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\base.py", line 837, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, upda
te_fields)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\base.py", line 923, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\base.py", line 962, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\model
s\sql\compiler.py", line 1107, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backe
nds\utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backend
  File "C:\Users\eloixir\Desktop\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backe
nds\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch
```

Comment: Django requires that your model have a primary key

Comment: But id field is added by default to the model in Django. Won't it act as primary key on its own?

Comment: Do you really have an Id field in your SQLite database ?

Comment: You need to tell is what the error is. Show the full message and traceback.

Comment: Please see my edit now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to write

```
event = form.save(commit=False)
event.save()
```

since the form data is already passed through request.POST, so just doing

```
form.save(commit=False)
```

should work for you. Also you don't need to get the form's cleaned_data unless you are doing some operations with them.
Hope it helps.

Comment: If I try to see if data is stored in db in interactive shell by giving p = createEvent.objects.all() and then print(p) gives me sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: home_createevent.id error!!!

Comment: do a couple of checks. first whether the app is added to settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS, second run makemigrations and migrate. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, app is in settings.py and makemigration and migrate works good. But I am getting error :(